# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo | E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, xml, error-handling

Greeting everyone, I'm trying to make an app with a navigational drawer and capable of having selectable contacts in one of the drawers but it keeps crashing.The app I built worked great for displaying the contact. When I started trying to implement the clicking on the contacts to navigate to another Fragment which would have the contact info, The App Wouldn't launch. Any help, even to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

[Project File](https://mega.nz)

Main Activity Java Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.example.v1z0.assignments.Utils.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);


        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started");

        initImageLoader();

        init();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void initImageLoader()
    {
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_activity_faculty) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    new ViewContactsFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    new SecondFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    new ThirdFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_fourth_layout) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    new FourthFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_fifth_layout) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    new FifthFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sixth_layout) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    new SixthFragment()).commit();

        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }
    private void init()
    {
        {
            ViewContactsFragment fragment = new ViewContactsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }




}
```

My Contact Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ContactFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ContactFragment";

    public ContactFragment(){
        super();
        setArguments(new Bundle());
    }

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.contactToolbar);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");

                                    //Toolbar Pre-req//
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

                                    //Go Back//
        ImageView ivBackArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBackArrow);
        ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked back arrow");
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
                                //Go To Edit//
        ImageView ivEdit = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivEdit);
        ivEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked edit");
                EditContactFragment fragment = new EditContactFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.edit_contact_fragment));
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: fragment" + getString(R.string.edit_contact_fragment));
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menuitem_delete:
                Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: deleting contact");
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Also the View Contact Fragment holding the contact information

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.v1z0.assignments.Models.Contact;
import com.example.v1z0.assignments.Utils.CustomListAdapter;


public class ViewContactsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FirstFragment";

    //images
    private  String testImageURL = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/man.jpg";
    private  String hgraham = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/hgraham.jpg";
    private  String dmitchell = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/dmitchell.png";
    private  String mnarayana = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/mnarayana.jpg";
    private  String hosborne = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/hosborne.jpg";
    private  String mreid = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/mreid.jpg";
    private  String esmall = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/esmall.jpg";
    private  String hsmith = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/hsmith.jpg";
    private  String ktooma = "cis.ncu.edu.jm/images/faculty/ktooma.jpg";

    //widgets etc
    private static final int STANDARD_APPBAR = 0;
    private static final int SEARCH_APPBAR = 1;
    private int mAppBarState;

    private AppBarLayout viewContactsBar, searchBar;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private ListView contactsList;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewcontacts, container, false);
        viewContactsBar = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.viewContactsToolbar);
        searchBar = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.searchtoolbar);
        contactsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started");

        setAppBarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
        setupContactsList();

                        //add contact navigation//
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabAddContact);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked fab");
            }

        });

                          //search contact navigation//
        ImageView ivSearchContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivSearchIcon);
        ivSearchContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked search");
                toggleToolBarState();
            }
        });

        ImageView ivBackArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBackArrow);
        ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked back arrow");
                toggleToolBarState();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    private void setupContactsList()
    {
        final ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Sheldon  Glenn ", "(876) 963-7281", "work", "sheldon.glenn@ncu.edu.jm  ", testImageURL));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Hamlet  Graham ", "(876) 963-7278", "work", "hamlet.graham@ncu.edu.jm ", hgraham));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Oche  Magbegor ", "(876) 963-7280", "work", "oche.magbegor@ncu.edu.jm ", testImageURL));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Damion  Mitchell ", "(876) 963-7285", "work", "damion.mitchell AT ncu.edu.jm  ", dmitchell));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Melvin  Narayana ", "(876) 963-7279", "work", "melvin.narayana@ncu.edu.jm", mnarayana));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Henry  Osborne ", "(876) 963-7282", "work", "Henry.Osborne@ncu.edu.jm  ", hosborne));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Marlon  Richards ", " (876) 963-7276", "work", "marlon.richards@ncu.edu.jm", testImageURL));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mrs.  E. Beverley  Small ", "(876) 963-7276", "work", "esmall@ncu.edu.jm  ", esmall));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Halzen  Smith ", "(876) 963-7284", "work", "hsmith@ncu.edu.jm  ", hsmith));
        contacts.add(new Contact("Mr.  Keron  Tooma ", " (876) 963-7283", "work", "keron.tooma@ncu.edu.jm  ", ktooma));

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_contactslistitem, contacts, "http://");
        contactsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        contactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to contact" + (R.string.contact_fragment));
                ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.edit_contact_fragment));
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: fragment" + getString(R.string.contact_fragment));
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

    }

    private void toggleToolBarState()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "toggleToolBarState: toggling AppBatState");
        if (mAppBarState == STANDARD_APPBAR)
        {
            setAppBarState(SEARCH_APPBAR);
        }
        else
        {
            setAppBarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    setAppBarState(STANDARD_APPBAR);
    }

    private void setAppBarState(int state)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "setAppBarState: changing app bar state to" + state);

        mAppBarState = state;

        if (mAppBarState == STANDARD_APPBAR)
        {
            searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewContactsBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //keyboard hide//
            View view = getView();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            try
            {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

            }catch (NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "setAppBarState: NullPointerException" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else if (mAppBarState == SEARCH_APPBAR)
        {
            viewContactsBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        //keyboard show//
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }



    }
}
```

LogCat Error

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2018-10-14 01:48:19.869 7041-7041/com.example.v1z0.assignments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.v1z0.assignments, PID: 7041
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.v1z0.assignments/com.example.v1z0.assignments.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080055 (com.example.v1z0.assignments:id/fragment_container) for fragment ViewContactsFragment{dcf4537 #0 id=0x7f080055}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080055 (com.example.v1z0.assignments:id/fragment_container) for fragment ViewContactsFragment{dcf4537 #0 id=0x7f080055}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1422)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7029)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2741)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

XML Fragments

Solo Contact Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

                    <include layout="@layout/snippet_contacttoolbar"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout2">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
                app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                android:id="@+id/contactImage" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/contactImage"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvName" />

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
                android:id="@+id/lvContactProperties">
            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

View Contact List Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/first">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout1">

            <include layout="@layout/snippet_searchtoolbar"/>
            <include layout="@layout/snippet_viewcontactstoolbar"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relLayout1">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/contactsList"></ListView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:id="@+id/textNoContacts"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add"
        android:id="@+id/fabAddContact"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Edit Page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I apologize for the lengthy question

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Post you xml that have fragment only

Comment: Body i said xml

Comment: I didn't see any usages of `FrameLayout` in  xml codes. Perhaps, you're trying to show `Fragment` on a `RelativeLayout` or something? However, that approach doesn't seem to be good with too many `RelativeLayout`s in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `init()` methond of MainActivity class file, you reference incorrect resource id.

```
    private void init()
    {
        {
            ViewContactsFragment fragment = new ViewContactsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);//not R.id.fragment_container
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to navylover answer. I also changed Fragment_container in my ViewContactFragment and it worked

```
contactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to contact" + (R.string.contact_fragment));
        ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.edit_contact_fragment));
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: fragment contentFrame" );
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```